# How to change the default Help browser for VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 changed the help system to run a little daemon and launch the system default web browser to view it.

I'm using Firefox for my system browser but would like to use Chrome for VS help.

Is there an option to change the Help browser that I'm not seeing in Tools|Options? If not, is there a workaround or registry setting to do this?

As a backup I've been using [H3Viewer](http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/viewer) but I'd like to be able to get context-sensitive F1 help from within the VS IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it [here](http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/news/overridingthedefaultviewer). Minor registry edit required:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Help\v1.0
(REG_SZ) HelpViewerProgID=c:\program files\Helpware\H3Viewer\H3Viewer.exe
```

This is the same path for a 32 or 64 bit OS, by the way. I had originally edited the Wow6432Node version and it didn't work. Use the direct path above regardless of OS bit width. Also make sure to restart the help server in the tray (and probably VS2010) for it to "take".